# auto reset sequence number to Zero with financial year in sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a sequence number which is new feature in sql 2012,
which will auto reset to 0 when a new financial year start,
financial year for me is 01 april 2015 to 31 march 2016.

I did RND from internet i got some hint to drop the sequence no,and then again recreate it.

Is it poosible to do with sequence number ,or else have to make new logic.
please help.

Comment: I think you'd be storing financial numbers (invoice numbers or other document ID's in that column), correct? If so, then I believe it is important to you to maintain the order number (sequence number) of the document in the future, correct? So, I don't think dropping the sequence and recreating it would be the best idea. Maybe you can give more details about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer to this question is - no, it's not possible. You can create sequence on numeric types only. But you can set some trigger, that will reset sequence object, when particular event occurs, like:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.Seq
RESTART
```

I think you have in your system something like closing procedure of financial year? So you can reset that sequence object as part of that procedure.